# How to style an id with css from an xml file

Tags: css, xml, schema

I'm styling an xml schema into a table, each of the names are a start of a column so they are in one row. I am unable to style the specific id selectors. Is #c1 not the correct syntax to style each specific column element id?

heres the xml

```
   <titles>
      <column id="c1">Symbol</column>
      <column id="c2">Name</column>
      <column id="c3">Last Sale</column>
      <column id="c4">Net Change</column>
      <column id="c5">% Change</column>
      <column id="c6">Volume</column>
   </titles>
```

Heres the css (color:green was just to jest to see if it would style it correctly.)

```
column{
    display:table-cell;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

column #c1{
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have numbers in CSS selectors.

You can use the CSS selector `:nth-child(n)` to style your elements.

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5dpdggd/

```
column {
    display:table-cell;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
column:nth-child(1) {
    color:green;
}
column:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
}
column:nth-child(3) {
    color:blue;
}
column:nth-child(4) {
    color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS for XML does not appear to use the same sort of attribute tags as you would expect for HTML. If you need styles for each column, I would convert this to HTML table, or use Javascript to style DOM elements.

Comment: I have to style the xml not html its a project.